# Swift Package Manager can't download Firebase dependency

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, fastlane, swift-package-manager

I ran into problems when building a project via fastlane.

I trying to build project with command:

```
gym(skip_package_dependencies_resolution: false)
```

And got error while resolving dependency graph, there is one dependency in project `https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk.git`:

> failed downloading 'https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/swiftpm/8.15.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.zip' which is required by binary target 'GoogleAppMeasurement': downloadError("Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1005 "The network connection was lost." UserInfo={_kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, NSURLSessionDownloadTaskResumeData={length = 5994, bytes = 0x62706c69 73743030 d4010203 04050607 ... 00000000 000016c4 }, NSUnderlyingError=0x600000627a20 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1005 "(null)" UserInfo={NSErrorPeerAddressKey=<CFData 0x6000030f5db0 [0x7ff84672dd70]>{length = 16, capacity = 16, bytes = 0x100201bbadc2495b0000000000000000}, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=53, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}}, _NSURLErrorFailingURLSessionTaskErrorKey=LocalDownloadTask <41C05101-B9D6-4CEB-8AB6-6E87B1FE818E>.<2>, _NSURLErrorRelatedURLSessionTaskErrorKey=(\n    "LocalDownloadTask <41C05101-B9D6-4CEB-8AB6-6E87B1FE818E>.<2>"\n), NSLocalizedDescription=The network connection was lost., NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/swiftpm/8.15.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.zip, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://dl.google.com/firebase/ios/swiftpm/8.15.0/GoogleAppMeasurement.zip, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=1}")

But if i try to build it with Xcode it's work well.

Also if i try to download `GoogleAppMeasurement` with link, everything loads successfully.

Comment: Resolve problem by updating Firebase minimum version from 8 to 9

Answer (score 2):

try to reset the package (from Files/Packages/Reset Packages Cache) with internet (not intranet) network then rerun. it will solved